# why use node.js in flutter??? and what's difference between not using node.js and using node.js?

Tags: firebase, flutter

I just wonder why flutter application using node.js??
I make mine only flutter and firestore but so much fcm in flutter docs teach me using node.js!
so I want to know what is node.js and why need to nodes in flutter.
I think just server is firebase // view and backend is flutter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need node to communicate to your firebase server, forming an API endpoint you can call in your flutter app. So technically node.js is more of backend environment code.

Comment: thank u! I need to know studying node.js!!! about better my application

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Firebase as your backend or you can choose to make your own backend creating an API. If you choose to create your own backend, there aren't differences to Flutter if that API will be developed using NodeJS / Dotnet / Django or any other framework.
The choose between your own backend or Firebase will depend of your project. Firebase is very scalable but you need to see the price of this, if your project becomes something big.

Comment: ahahahah!!!!! absolutely I understood thank u!!!